# Studying convergence of the series involving fractional part

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fractional-part

I need to study where the following series is convergent:
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\{ n \alpha\}}{n}$$
Here $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. I've already proven that it converges if $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ and that it diverges if $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q} \ \backslash \ \mathbb{N}$ (It is done rather easily, namely by comparison with the Harmonic Series).

What should I do when $\alpha$ is irrational?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\alpha\not \in \Bbb{Z}$,

$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\{n\alpha\}}n$ diverges because one of $\{n\alpha\}, \{(n+1)\alpha\}$ is larger than $\min(\{\alpha\},1-\{\alpha\})$.

Comment: Thanks for the short & rigorous solution!

Comment: Ahh, I see what the argument is. Could you elaborate somewhat, because while I believe you  I can't quite convince myself that "one of $\{n\alpha\}, \{(n+1)\alpha\}$ is larger than $\min(\{\alpha\},1-\{\alpha\})$" is true

Comment: The case $\{\alpha\} \in (0,1/2]$ is easy, if $\{n\alpha\} \in [0,\{\alpha\})$ then $\{ (n+1)\alpha\} = \{n\alpha\}+\{\alpha\} \in [\{\alpha\},2\{\alpha\})$ @QC_QAOA

Comment: Gotcha, understand now +1